# Using taxonomy filter produces duplicate content in node view

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

Each "info page" node on my site has a field referencing or more taxonomy terms from the 'info page' vocabulary.

I'm trying to use a node view to make it possible to find any/all content which references a particular taxonomy term. I'm getting duplicates in my node view whenever content has more than one taxonomy term and "Any" taxonomy terms are all searched. Within the returned results, nodes repeat a number of times equal to the number of terms the node references.
Eg. a node with 4 different taxonomy terms shows up 4 times in my table of results after searching using the view.

The view is output as an html table and using the filter -
Taxonomy:has taxonomy terms (i've selected all terms in my info page vocabulary) and exposed the filter.

The search works fine when any specific, but I get duplicates when searching "Any" terms within the vocabulary.

There are countless articles about how to solve duplication issues in views, none have worked for me so far, so I'm hoping that maybe the issue is with the way my view is setup.

Here's the export http://pastebin.com/P7EkC8KX

Answer (score 3):

Under advanced, click aggregation settings then check Aggregation.  Then click Query Settings and check Distinct.

Comment: Hi CR. I did already attempt try this; no results are returned when aggregation is enabled.

Comment: @eadumbire Try also setting the distinct box to checked in the Query Settings if you haven't already.  I've had issues where just checking aggregation will either produce the same duplicate results or even none at all like you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are displaying the output as a table, try editing the table settings so that you group by the taxonomy term. Then in your fields make sure to exclude that field from display if you don't want it duplicated. So you could have the view show:

Taxonomy term 1:
-first node title referencing this term
-second node title referencing this term
-third node title referencing this term

Taxonomy term 2:
-first node title referencing this term
-second node title referencing this term
-third node title referencing this term

Etc.